# String to String Array Android project

Tags: java, android, string, split

**On developing an Android project I have got stacked in position**

I don't want to describe because it is simple.

```
String str = "Physics,Chemistry,Biology"
```

This is my ***String*** and three queries are divided by comma.
One of my method returns string like this.

So I want to make it to a string array.
This will like that dividing comma based.

```
String[] strArr = {"Physics", "Chemistry", "Biology"};
```

Comment: [`String.split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) ?

Comment: @Michael Could you.please write it for me.

Comment: for more understanding you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a method in String class that can help you convert it,
but you should give this method the regex , in your case regex is `","`

you can use this method to convert it:

```
   public String[] convertToArray(String str, String regex){
    return str.split(regex);
   }

   String[] str = convertToArray(str, ",");
```

Answer (score 0):

String[] strArr = str.split(“,”);

Comment: Thanks. I have another String array String[] subjects = {};

I want that the splitted array will replace it.